# Using PolyLabel with GeoJSON data and Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geojson

I am attempting to use the [PolyLabel](https://github.com/mapbox/polylabel) library with GeoJSON data and the Google Maps API to generate appropriately placed labels for irregular polygons.  The documentation says that the library accepts polygon coordinates in *GeoJSON-like format*.

The problem is that I cannot figure out what data to pass from the Google Maps API data layer to PolyLabel to get the best fit label position.

```
polygons.forEach(function (feature) {
    var geo = feature.getGeometry();

    var position = polylabel(???, 1.0);

    var mapLabel = new MapLabel({
        position: position,
        text: feature.getProperty("LABEL"),
        fontSize: 25,
        fontColor: "red",
        map: map
    })

    currentLabels.push(mapLabel);
});
```

I have tried multiple variations on passing in the feature, the geometry, the raw coordinates, and constructing polygons from the coordinates.

It is also worth noting that the GeoJSON data contains a mixture of Polygons and MultiPolygons.

Thank you.

Comment: https://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#id4

Answer (score 1):

definitely difficult to see, but you can find it here.
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/polylabel/index.d.ts

for each point in the polygon, you have [x, y].
Each polygon is then [[x,y]...], and polylabel takes array of polygons.